# Segmentation fault using max_element() and min_element() in C++

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, std

When I try to run this program there is a segmentation fault that is caused in this section:

```
      std::vector<double> dist1(dist);

      dist1.erase(std::remove(dist1.begin(), dist1.end(), 0), dist1.end());

      max = *std::max_element(dist1.begin(),dist1.end());

      min = *std::min_element(dist1.begin(),dist1.end());
```

It is the use of the max_element() and min_element() that cause the segmentation fault but I do not see why. What I doing here is copying a vector "dist" to "dist1", removing all occurrences of "0" in the new vector and then searching for the minimum and maximum values from the remaining items in "dist" "max" and "min" are double type variables previously declared. "dist" is previously declared as

```
 std::vector<double> dist; //vector used to hold the distances between adjacent vertices

 dist.resize(size);
```

The code compiles otherwise with g++ on a Linux server. Please advice.

Comment: If every code that compiled successfully was automatically bug free, I'd be out of a job.

Answer (score 4):

> It is the use of the max_element() and min_element() that cause the
>   segmentation fault but I do not see why.

No, it is the *dereferencing* of the result which causes the segmentation fault.

If you use those functions with an **empty** range, then the end iterator is returned. Any attempt to dereference that iterator is undefined behaviour. A segmentation fault is one typical but not necessary result of undefined behaviour.

You must either prevent your vector from being empty (and ideally add an assertion for that) or change your program logic to support an empty vector.

Option 1:

```
// code that prevents dist1 from being empty goes here
// ...
auto const max_iter = std::max_element(dist1.begin(), dist1.end());
assert(max_iter != dist1.end());
auto const max = *max_iter;
```

Option 2:

```
auto const max_iter = std::max_element(dist1.begin(), dist1.end());
if (max_iter == dist1.end())
{
    // do something to handle the special situation
}
else
{
    auto const max = *max_iter;
    // normal program flow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably *dist1* is empty after applying *remove/erase* operations.

In case of empty input interval [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) return the end of the input range. As a consequence you try to dereference *dist1.end()* and crash happens.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to get it to work. Instead of just using the copy constructor

```
std::vector<double> dist1(dist)
```

I also declared and resized my new vector as follows:

```
std::vector<double> dist1(size);
dist1=dist;
```

One thing that still bothers me: Shouldn't the copy constructor done all of this?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. This did not fix it, just coincidentally/randomly masked the bug.